# Decline unfunded place and reapply?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, etiquette, funding

I hold three offers from top-tier universities in the UK for a PhD in the humanities, with three great supervisors. However, one of the three has already let me know that the department has not nominated me for internal funding, which makes me quite pessimistic for the other two as well.

So, should I fail to get **any** funding from any of the three (and facing therefore the haunting perspective of a self-funded PhD), would it be a good idea to take a year off, work on my CV and skills, and then reapply to the same three uni's next year?

In no way would it be a 'wasted' year, since I will likely publish 2-3 papers (already working on two), I'll finish my Master's (I have yet to graduate), improve two foreign languages other than English, better refine my writing samples and researhc proposal and so on - so that I hope my profile will get more competitive for funding next year.

What I wonder is if this is frowned upon. I mean, if the admissions committee knew that I was admitted and then declined my unfunded offer, would this go against my chances of readmission (and funding)? Would the greater academic strength of my improved profile offset this possible act of academic 'unkindness'?

And how usual is it to turn down an unfunded offer hoping for funding in the following admission cycle?

(possible duplicate, as there are some similar questions, but the core of mine is the funding issue and how frowned upon is it to decline and reapply because of this)

P.S.: I am an EU national, so also consider Brexit and its possible consequences on funding awarding to non-UK applicants.

Comment: No funding means you are free to do what you like there as much as during a year taken off, doesn't it?

Comment: @Karl I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Regarding your P.S.: In all honesty, we don't know the possible consequences. Either you will be treated as a foreign national with funding decisions depending on the universities policies, or you will be still treated as a European (also, it still depends on policies) Right now, laws have not changed. If you get funding now that is given for a fixed term, I would expect it to be valid, even after Brexit. Regarding Visa and Work permits, currently the official website states it has not changed with Brexit and that is all we can say.

Comment: @skymningen that is the question: if I get funding now (i.e. for entry in 2017/18) that is guaranteed for the whole duration of my course. This might not be the case in 2018/19, though. Anyway if I don't get any funding this year that's not even something to worry about: I'm mostly concerned about changes in fee status (non-EU students pay *way* more than Home/EU as of now, as you certainly know) combined with possible cuts on awards for EU applicants as opposed to British ones.

Comment: As of me checking earlier this week, the future of EU-Student status after the full Brexit is still unclear, so there is nothing definite anyone could answer you. It is just too early. I am in the position of probably looking to work in UK (for personal reasons) from next year and I am currently stuck with a "Que sera, sera"-attitude.

Comment: @skymningen thank you, you're probably right: it's still too soon. So, apart from my P.S.: any thoughts on how 'appropriate' it is to decline an offer merely for funding reasons and then reapply hoping for better luck (and a stronger profile)?

Comment: I'm not in academia, so a general query for others. Could the OP ask the departments about past applicants who were accepted unfunded but then re-applied later and got funding? I know it's all relative--next year's applicants could be even stronger, but knowing that it has or hasn't happened ever might be useful.

Comment: @mkennedy of course I would be interested in knowing those figures, I just don't know how polite it would be to ask. Anyway my prospective advisor repeatedly told me that the level of this year's applicants was remarkably stronger than average, so I'm guessing I could do better next year (if I work on my profile at the same time).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its answer depends on the resolution of an ongoing political question.

Comment: People are saying this is off-topic because of the brexit part of the question. That is a small PS on the end, and not the main meat of the question. I could see an argument that the whole question is off-topic on the basis of not being widely applicable, but since most of the close votes are on the basis of the EU stuff I'm voting to leave open for now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered asking the PhD supervisors if they do have funding? UK universities rarely have a pool of funds for PhD students. These would have to come from a funding programme, where potentially your supervisor has applied to and has got the funding for the PhD position.

It might be a good idea to ask all three of them, not only to see if there would be the opportunity to develop funding applications, but also see whether they have anything in the works for next year. Funding depending on the programme and situation may apply differently to EU citizens post-Brexit. However no one will be able to tell you accurately. At least for Scotland, the Scottish government has promised that funding for EU citizens will remain the same for 2019.